# Is natural semantics a total or partial function

Tags: semantics

I have the following def's

`Sns : Stm → (State ֒→ State)`

`Sns[S] = s' (if <S,s> -> s') else undefined`

I'm wondering if Sns is a partial or total function. I think it's total since it always returns a partial function, given any statement.

But the book I'm reading (semantic with application by wiley, pg 41) says:

> Note that Sns is a well-defined **partial** function because of
>   Theorem 2.9. The need for partiality is demonstrated by the statement
>   `while true do skip` that always loops.

I'm very confused.

Comment: If your system is normalizing, then the semantics is total over the well-formed expressions. If your system is not normalizing, then the semantics is partial, because it can assign a "meaning" only to expressions that terminate.

Comment: It is possible that the book is considering `Sns` as a two-argument function, taking statement `S` and state `s` as arguments. In such interpretation, it is partial (for your imperative language with infinite loops).